# Saleor - Trying to modify the dashboard (add 'Job Title' to 'Customer' / 'Account')

Tags: django, reactjs, saleor

I'm new here :) I'm trying to build an eCommerce site using Saleor as the framework, I'm having trouble understanding the framework with the intention to modify the admin dashboard and database.

To start simple and practice, I'm trying to add a 'Job Title' field to customers, and want this to be editable on the dashboard.

Currently, I've performed a django migration and the new field is liked up to the database - I modified `/saleor/saleor/account/modles.py`

```py
class User(PermissionsMixin, AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
```

PostgreSQL also works fine

```sql
SELECT * FROM account_user;
```

[SQL Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxZiy.png)

Where I'm completely stuck is actually getting this field to work with the dashboard/ appear.

I've gone through editing the files where 'First Name' field appears, as the django `/templates/` file seems to reference a 'form' I can only assume is run by ReactJS (which I'm not as familiar with as Python).

The files I've modified (and effectively copied what existed for 'First Name') are:

```
added jobTitle: formData.jobTitle, to line 111 on static/dashboard-next/customers/views/CustomerDetails.tsx
added block from line 128 on static/customers/components/CustomerDetails/CustomerDetails.tsx
added block from line 24 and 61 on static/customers/components/CustomerDetailsPage/CustomerDetailsPage.tsx
```

I'd really appreciate if someone can help point me in the right direction of how saleor / django / reactjs goes from website -> actual html :)

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a `ModelForm` for User?

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes, located in `forms.py` for Customer, thank you so much!!! So simple, but I've been scratching my head for over a week on this!

Comment: No problem! Happy coding