# How can I create a Saleor plugin that is a Django app?

Tags: django, saleor

I'm trying to add a Saleor plugin that is also a Django app. The reason is that I want to be able to use Django migrations for it. I've created regular Saleor plugins before, which work fine. I'm not very familiar with Django apps yet, but the documentation makes sense to me. What I'm utterly confused about is the combination of the two concepts.

- Which directory does it go into? Does it go into the saleor/plugins directory like all other regular Saleor plugins? Or directly into the saleor directory, like all other Django apps? [The only somewhat related answer I could find](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61558112/13426235) suggests using `manage.py startapp`, which creates the plugin in the root directory, *next to* the saleor directory, adding to my confusion.
- How to install the Django app as a Saleor plugin? [The official documentation](https://docs.saleor.io/docs/developer/extending/plugins#loading-your-plugin) instructs to use a `setup.py` and suggests that:

  > If your plugin is a Django app, the package name (the part before the equal sign) will be added to Django's INSTALLED_APPS so you can take advantage of Django's features such as ORM integration and database migrations.

  However, none of the built-in Saleor plugins or Django apps are using this setup.py mechanism, and I cannot find any Saleor-related example using this, and haven't been able to come up with anything coherent without such an example (also due to the previous point). The documentation appears to suggest that, when using setup.py, the Django app would automatically be added to Django's `INSTALLED_APPS`. Or do I have to add it there myself?

Does anyone know of an example of how to create a Saleor plugin as a Django app, preferably with working migrations?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same question. Especially since it's advised to never change any core files, how would thhis be possible

Comment: Hi @Rouzbeh, this question was for an old version of Saleor, where plugins were still the official way to add functionality. This has changed completely with Saleor 3. Now the only supported way is to create a separate microservice ("Saleor app", https://docs.saleor.io/docs/3.x/developer/extending/apps/quickstart), exposing its own API and communicating with Saleor via GraphQL and webhooks. You're of course free to fork and modify Saleor, and to add your own plugins somehow, but with the complete lack of support and documentation for this, I really wouldn't advise it anymore.

Comment: Thanks @Heiko. Can this new approach handle extending the database, like adding relations? Let's say in my app I create two many-to-many product relationships called artists and labels, and want to display artists & labels along with products on product list pages.

Would I need to implement an app with a GraphQL endpoint that first retrieves all products from saleor, then makes another call for artists, then another for brands in my app, and merge everything back together? 

Performance wise that sounds like a terrible idea. Or am I missing something? Any hints?

Comment: No, unfortunately, you cannot access Saleor's own database at all using this approach, and your app will be completely stand-alone, with its own database. You could consider saving the artist or label ID in product/variant metadata, and you can then filter products by this metadata.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that this is the best way to do it, but this works for me, for now:

The app/plugin can live anywhere, but I think it makes sense to put it into `saleor/plugins`.

1. Create a folder for the plugin, e.g. `saleor/plugins/product_import`
2. Run `python3 manage.py startapp product_import saleor/plugins/product_import`. This creates the standard Django app template in your folder.
3. I tried the `setup.py` part from the [official docs](https://docs.saleor.io/docs/3.0/developer/extending/plugins#loading-your-plugin), but it didn't appear to do anything for me, so I finally ignored it and manually added the app to `saleor/settings.py`:

   ```py
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
     ...
     "saleor.plugins.product_import",
     ...
   ]
   ```

   This enables all the usual Django app features, such as migrations (run `python3 manage.py makemigrations product_import` after defining some models in `models.py`), commands, etc.
4. To turn the Django app into a Saleor plugin (to be able to use all the Saleor plugin hooks), create a `plugin.py` like this one:

   ```py
   from django.http import JsonResponse
   from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIRequest

   from ..base_plugin import BasePlugin

   class ProductImportPlugin(BasePlugin):
     """Imports products into Saleor"""

     PLUGIN_NAME = "Product Import Plugin"
     PLUGIN_ID = "product_import"
     DEFAULT_ACTIVE = True
     PLUGIN_DESCRIPTION = (
       "Imports products into Saleor."
     )

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

     def webhook(self, request: WSGIRequest, path: str, previous_value) -> JsonResponse:
       return JsonResponse({"status": "works"})
   ```

   And add it to the list of Saleor plugins in `saleor/settings.py`:

   ```py
   PLUGINS = [
     ...,
     "saleor.plugins.product_import.plugin.ProductImportPlugin",
   ]
   ```

Comment: where do I register my site ? as per the django docs, it says we need to register our app in admin.py. But in saleor, I don't see any app registered nor the admin.py file. 

When I include my app in Installed Apps, it says couldn't import xxx app. 

Could you please help me on that. Also, if there is a sample that you can share that would be more helpful.

Comment: hey, and how do you call this plugin later on?

Comment: With your Plugin approach is it possible to extend the GraphQL schema?